# flowchart.js rtl (right to left) options

Tags: jquery, right-to-left

I'm working on RTL (Right to left) version. It is possible to create right to left direction?
For the official site flow chat the link is here:[1]:http://flowchart.js.org/ . actually I'm trying to converting flow chart into RTL version. If you have any suggestion then tell me.